# Change the resolution of a jpeg image using C#

Tags: c#, jpeg, resolution

I need to modify the vertical and horizontal resolutions without changing the image dimensions.

Comment: And you want to know how to do so? Have you made an attempt yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Bitmap.SetResolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setresolution.aspx) Method.

Answer (score 0):

If all you have is GDI, have a look at this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/imageresize.aspx).

You can save the [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx) to a JPEG file using this snippet:

```
bmp.Save("picture.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: The question was about changing the resolution WITHOUT resizing. The article is all about resizing.

Comment: Okay, hehe. Guess I'm blind today.

Comment: On the other hand, with some modification he could use some of the stuff in the article to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution is contained in EXIF tags within the JPEG file.

Here's one article that gives source code for doing similar things in C#:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/EXIF_tag_Editor.aspx